# why can't SpriteKit find my images?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I'm following the SpriteKit Tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's site. I've created a project with the SpriteKit template. The problem is that my image is showing up as a big white rectangle with a big red X in it. There are no errors in the log. I'm also reading from the SpriteKit Programming Guide and Texture Atlas help. I'm assuming this is a project settings issue or folder structures issue. I'm pretty new to Xcode. Here's what my project looks like in Xcode:

```
MyGameProj (the top level, with the little blue xcode icon)
-->MyGameProj (yellow folder)
 -->Assets (yellow folder)
   -->Atlases (yellow folder)
     -->dungeon.atlas (blue folder)
       dungeon_1.jpg
       dungeon_2.jpg
       dungeon_3.jpg
       hero_trans.gif
  various .h and .m files
```

At first, I had the `Assets` folder outside of the `MyGameProj` folder. Neither worked

Here's the code. This is within `MyScene`, `initWithSize()`:

```
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"dungeon"];
SKTexture *texture = [atlas textureNamed:@"hero_trans.gif"];
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[self addChild:self.player];
```

I have gone into the build settings and turned on atlas generation.

Comment: See my answer below. But also just thought - why gifs? If you want the appearance of movement etc, better off with a sequence of images animated

Comment: I don't know why it was a gif; there was no animation; just a sprite I got from somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can use .gif files with texture atlases in `Sprite-Kit`. I've experimented with your code a bit. Putting the .gif file outside of the atlas and using 
`spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` instead, works.

Test 1: same code as you, .gif in dungeon.atlas: doesn't work

```
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"dungeon"];
SKTexture *texture = [atlas textureNamed:@"Seven_segment_display-animated.gif"];
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[self addChild:self.player];
```

Test 2: node created with `spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` with .gif from dungeon.atlas: doesn't work

```
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Seven_segment_display-animated.gif"];
self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[self addChild:self.player];
```

Test 3: load .gif file into project itself (not atlas) e.g. Assets folder: This works

```
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Seven_segment_display-animated.gif"];
self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[self addChild:self.player];
```

Comment: @LearnCocos2D it appears but doesn't actually do anything, no GIF animation

Comment: That was I thought too. We cannot use gifs in `SKTextureAtlas`

Comment: Thanks, that was it; I changed it to a .png and it worked; it would be nice if this was in the SpriteKit docs

Comment: I don't see any difference between test 2 and test 3 in your code

Comment: @OMGPOP - in test 2 the image is in the atlas folder, in test 3 it is outside of it

Comment: @OMGPOP yeah - gifs won't work as SKSpriteNode, my test 3 above shows the first frame but that's all. You're better off with animation anyway

Comment: it also appears to fail on files with the .ico extension